# Why do I get a segment fault when I have an array length greater than 2

Tags: c, linux, assembly

I am using malloc to create an array (before I get criticized for using malloc in c++, I only wish to do this because I would like to learn) of length length. Any time that I have length greater than 2 I get a segment fault, and I'm not sure why. When I used a debugger I get a segment fault on a line that does not exist when I get the compiler to output the .S file.

This is for Linux x86-64

Initially I tried creating the array is x64 asm but when I kept getting segment errors I tried writing the same thing in c++, but I kept getting segment errors

c++ code that does what fillArrayWithRandom64 without printing

```
int main(){
    uint64_t length=4;
    uint64_t* arr=(uint64_t*)malloc(8*length);
    for(uint64_t i=0;i<length;i++){
        *(arr+i)=genRandom64();
        cout<<"Value at "<<i<<":"<<*(arr+i)<<endl;
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Generates array and fills with random numbers

```
fillArrayWithRandom64:#rdi is length
#returns pointer to array
    cmp     rdi,0
    jle     _fillArrayWithRandom64Bad

    push    rbp
    mov     rbp,rsp

    push    rdi     #-8     length
    imul    rdi,8
    call    malloc@PLT
    push    rax     #-16    pointer
    pushq   0       #-24    counter

    _fillArrayWithRandom64L1:
        call    genRandom64
        mov     rbx,[rbp-16]
        mov     rcx,[rbp-24]
        mov     [rbx+rcx*8],rax

        inc     rcx
        mov     [rbp-24],rcx
        cmp     rcx,[rbp-8]
        jl      _fillArrayWithRandom64L1

    mov     rax,[rbp-16]
    mov     rsp,rbp
    pop     rbp
    ret
    _fillArrayWithRandom64Bad:
        mov     rax,0
        ret
```

My random number function

```
genRandom64:#returns 64
    call    rand@PLT
    push    rax
    call    rand@PLT
    shl     rax,32
    pop     rbx
    or      rax,rbx
    ret
```

My expected output was "Value at (i):(some random number)"
I got Segment fault (core dumped)

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: Target received a signal: SIGSEGV, Segment fault

Comment: Where at? Which line?

Comment: One obvious problem is that `rbx` is a callee-saved register and you destroy it in both of your functions. Use `rdx` instead or save and restore it.

Comment: @Jester That solved the problem thank you!

Comment: The stack pointer should be aligned to a multiple of 16 when calling `malloc`.